# How to access addressbook without copying the whole contact to an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

This is how I do things now:

```
-(void)vPopulateContact
{
    NSArray * arPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( self.addressBook));
    NSMutableArray * arPeople1 = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id somePeople in arPeople) {
        ABRecordRef ABPerson= (__bridge ABRecordRef)somePeople; //do not transfer ownership
        RCABRecordRef * abRRWrapper = [[RCABRecordRef alloc]init];
        abRRWrapper.abRecordRef=ABPerson;
        [arPeople1 addObject:abRRWrapper];
    }


    NSArray * arPeople2=[arPeople1 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        RCABRecordRef * abr1 = (RCABRecordRef*) obj1;
        NSDate * date1=abr1.dDatedAdded;
        RCABRecordRef * abr2 = (RCABRecordRef*) obj2;
        NSDate * date2=abr2.dDatedAdded;
        return [date2 compare:date1];
    }];

    self.allMyContacts=[arPeople2 subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(200,arPeople2.count))].mutableCopy;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Copying the whole address book to nsarray is memory hogging. So I want something that works without it.

Say I want to find the 5th person or stuff like that. How would I do so?

Should I just copy the person's ID and then look up address book based on id?

Comment: "Copying the whole address book to nsarray is memory hogging." -- Then again, most people don't have gazillions of contacts either. A few UIViews or UIViewControllers will likely hog a lot more memory than the contents of the entire address book.

Comment: I got 1400 contacts. I do not think they hog memory. However, my program often crash with memory warning. I wonder what's using the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Searching is explained in [Searching an Address Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/Searching.html). Example:

```
ABAddressBook *AB = [ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook];
ABSearchElement *nameIsSmith = [ABPerson searchElementForProperty:kABLastNameProperty
                                                            label:nil
                                                              key:nil
                                                            value:@"Smith"
                                                       comparison:kABEqualCaseInsensitive];
NSArray *peopleFound = [AB recordsMatchingSearchElement:nameIsSmith];
```

There is no way to restrict the amount of results to a given number. A workaround would be to match by name initials for each letter in the alphabet.